# Amazon AWS authorization error I am getting this error on the AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have made changes in the security group but those changes are not visible and hence I am unable to load my apache server. Any solutions to this?

User: arn:aws:sts::276097608444:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/user1553276=pawar.jitendra@iiitg.ac.in is not authorized to perform: compute-optimizer:GetEnrollmentStatus on resource: * with an explicit deny

Edit: The issue has been solved. If you are unable to open your server from your AWS console. Try copy-pasting the link manually instead of redirecting.

Comment: Well, the solution is quite funny. I tried creating new instances and doing all things but nothing seemed to work. Then instead of clicking the hyperlink of my instance, I just copy-pasted the URL into the browser, and voila, it opened. The above-stated error is still there on my console and I still don't have an answer for it. I thought my server wasn't opening because of this error but that was not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not about security groups but about no permissions to do `GetEnrollmentStatus` action. Unfortunately, AWS Educate Starter Accounts are **very limited**. A non-exhaustive list of supported services is at:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://awseducate-starter-account-services.s3.amazonaws.com/AWS_Educate_Starter_Account_Services_Supported.pdf)

The only thing you can do is to contact AWS Educate support and ask if they can modify your permissions for you, which probably they will not. If you are student, you can contact your AWS Educate educator from your institution about that.